# AEM client lib switch between JS/CSS version

Tags: aem, sling, jcr, crx

my questions is, has anyone come across something like e.g switching JS lib between aem60 and aem63. 
What I mean is, e.g: in AEM6.0 instance, my component will use [Parsleyjs](http://parsleyjs.org/) version 2.2.0, now because we are slowly upgrading each instance to AEM6.3, and we use one single code base repo for all instances, so we need ability when AEM6.3 instance is running, component will have the ability to auto switch to Parsleyjs version 2.8.1

My current thinking is, under etc/clientlib/myproject/liberies,  i have two versions of parsleyjs with two different categories. please see screenshot:
[image]

so parsleyjs 2-2 and 2-8.

Then in my etc/clientlib/myproject/components/search-box, here it lays the JS CSS code for this component, and I wish to do something like screenshot below for switching parsleyjs version for different AEM version platform.
[image]

Any suggestions or better appoach?
Please provide example answers with code or screenshot
Thanks for help.

Comment: just curious, why not migrating to AEM6.4

Comment: Use run modes for different settings on different environments.

Answer (score 0):

> AEM `clientlibs` have no way to do this OOTB.
>
> **DISCLAIMER:** the solution I am about to describe will unnecessarily complicate your build.. You might be better off making the changes manually and deploy since this is a temporary thing. Additionally, this is not a complete fix. it's an approach you *can* follow to get the results you want.

Find a maven plugin that will do `string replacement` at *build time*.

Essentially you'd have an expression in your `clientlib` `xml`, something like:

```
.
. 
dependencies="${parsleyClientlib}"
.
.
```

then you'd pass a flag to your maven build like `-Paem.version=6.3`, and based on that flag, the maven plugin would replace `${parsleyClientlib}` with the intended dependency name.

Possible plugins to try:

- [maven-replacer-plugin](https://github.com/beiliubei/maven-replacer-plugin/wiki/Usage-Guide)
- [string-template-maven-plugin](https://github.com/kevinbirch/string-template-maven-plugin)
- [groovy-template-maven-plugin](http://summitsystemsinc.github.io/groovy-template-maven-plugin/advanced.html)

Hope this helps.